# Socket connect error c socket

Tags: c++, winsock

I made a simple client program who connect to server via port 80;

```
int v=connect(mysocket,(struct sockaddr *)&server,sizeof(server));
if(v==SOCKET_ERROR){
                            cout<<"error connecting to server";



                            }
 if (v==0) cout<<"connected"<<endl;
```

its says connect return 0 if success.
but i get the error;
can you please tell me when i must use htonl or htons i used only `server.sin_port=htons(80);`
should i use `server.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr("someip_ignorethis");` or i must use

```
server.sin_addr.s_addr=htonl(inet_addr("someip_ignorethis"));
```

what is the problem WHY AND WHEN i need to use host to network conversation,how does it make my program portable???.
what socket i must use? socket version 2,2? 
THNAKS FOR THE HELP!
I get 10038 ERROR HELP FIX MY CODE pastebin.com/4pdqsGqW

Comment: You say you are getting an error, but you don't say **what** error you are getting. `connect()` returns -1 on failure, and then `WSAGetLastError()` returns the actual error code. Yes, you must fill in the `server.sin_addr.s_addr` so `connect()` knows what IP to connect to. You do not use `htonl()` with `inet_addr()`.

Comment: it doest let me know what error

Comment: @RemyLebeau connect return 0 when success and socket_error on error? how u know it return -1 on failure??

Comment: i keep getting error at connection! help me i cant connect!

Comment: Please show how you are filling in the `server` struct. `SOCKET_ERROR` is -1.  If `connect()` returns -1, call `WSAGetLastError()` to find out why it failed, eg: `if(v==SOCKET_ERROR){ cout<<"Unable to connect to server! Error " << WSAGetLastError(); ... }`

Comment: @RemyLebeau ERROR CODE 10038

Comment: FULL CODE HERE http://pastebin.com/4pdqsGqW

Answer (score 1):

If you had bothered to use your debugger and debug the code yourself, you would have found that your `mySocket` variable is always 0, because you are not initializing it correctly.

This line:

```
if (mysocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==INVALID_SOCKET){
```

Is effectively the same as this:

```
if (mysocket=(socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP)==INVALID_SOCKET)){
```

If `socket()` succeeds, `==INVALID_SOCKET` evaluates as false, so 0 is assigned to `mysocket`.  Read up on [Operator Precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence).  The `==` operator has a higher precedence than the `=` operator.

To fix it, change that line to this instead:

```
if ((mysocket=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP))==INVALID_SOCKET){
```

Or better, get out of the habit of assigning and comparing a variable in the same statement:

```
mysocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,IPPROTO_TCP);
if (mysocket==INVALID_SOCKET){
```

Also, if you had bothered to pay attention to your compiler's output messages, you would have seen that your `"CONNECTED!"` message is code that is never reached, because it is inside the curly braces for when `connect()` fails, but there is a `return` before you print the message.

Try this code instead:

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <iostream.h>
#include <windows.h>

//#define portnumber 80
using namespace std;
//Winsock Library

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    WSADATA ws = {0};
    int v = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &ws);
    if (v != 0)
    {
        cout << "error initialising winsock: " << v << endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "winsock started" << endl;

    SOCKET mysocket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP);
    if (mysocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        cout << "error creating socket: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "socket created" << endl;

    struct sockaddr_in server = {0};
    server.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("84.95.234.174");
    //cout << inet_ntoa(server.sin_addr) << endl;
    server.sin_port = htons(80);

    if (connect(mysocket, (struct sockaddr *)&server, sizeof(server)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        cout << "error connecting to server: " << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        getchar();
        return 1;
    }

    cout << "CONNECTED!" << endl;

    getchar();

    closesocket(mysocket);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: i want to know how to fix my code not to use other people code what is wrong in my code ? how fix it? pastebin.com/4pdqsGqW

Comment: I have updated my answer.  Next time, DEBUG YOUR CODE YOURSELF BEFORE ASKING FOR HELP!

Answer (score 0):

10038 is `WSAENOTSOCK`. Clearly the value of `socket` is invalid.

You should have found all that out for yourself before you posted, and looked up what the error meant as well.

Comment: HOW fix it? can u tell me what wrong in my code?  pastebin.com/4pdqsGqW

Comment: @user2933572: You are not passing a valid `SOCKET` to `connect()`.  That is why you are getting an `WSAENOTSOCK` error.

Comment: I won't comment on code that isn't posted here, but it shouldn't be necessary for such a trivial error.

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I use this and it never fails me..

```
struct addrinfo *it = nullptr, *result = nullptr;
getaddrinfo(Address.c_str(), nullptr, nullptr, &result);
for (it = result; it != nullptr; it = it->ai_next)
{
    sockaddr_ipv4 = reinterpret_cast<sockaddr_in*>(it->ai_addr);
    Address = inet_ntoa(sockaddr_ipv4->sin_addr);
    if (Address != "0.0.0.0") break;
}
freeaddrinfo(result);
```

And I use:

```
struct sockaddr_in SockAddr;
memset(&SockAddr, 0, sizeof(SockAddr));
SockAddr.sin_port = htons(Port);
SockAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
SockAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = Address == "INADDR_ANY" ? htonl(INADDR_ANY) : inet_addr(Address.c_str());


if (connect(socket, reinterpret_cast<SOCKADDR*>(&SockAddr), sizeof(SockAddr)) == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    //print error.. clean up..
}
```

What it does is it checks the address. If it is INADDR_ANY, then it will use htonl. If not, it uses inet_addr to convert the address into an IP. Htonl on the other hand just converts the address into network byte order.

Comment: i dont understand this code can u pls just answer my questions. i want to use my code . thanks!

Comment: I did answer your questions though.. I said if the address is INADDR_ANY, then use htonl. Otherwise, use inet_addr. And to answer why you need to use it. Because you need to convert the address to a binary representation that the socket can use (inet_addr does this). As for why you get the error, I cannot tell because you barely posted any code at all.. Version 2.2 on windows is of course better so you should use that. If you can't, then it is fine. The code will still work. Your program will be protable if you #ifdef all windows api calls or just avoid them.

Comment: i use devcpp and i added to the linker . should i use something else? its not working because of devcp i must use other ide?

Comment: You do not need to use `htonl()` with `INADDR_ANY`.  `INADDR_ANY` has all of its bits set to 1, so it is the same numeric value in big endian and little endian.

Comment: @RemyLebeau `INADDR_ANY` has all its bits set to *zero.*

Comment: @EJP: yes, sorry, that is what I meant. `INADDR_BROADCAST` and `INADDR_NONE` are set to all ones instead.

Comment: This doesn't solve the problem. The problem is the value of `mysocket`.